# Groups of Consecutive Numbers Regex Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match 4 couples of repeated numbers. This is the Pattern 5XXYYZZKK.

I have this sample
`533992288`

I was able to write this regex

```
.{1}(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})
```

The problem with this regex is that it does not recognize the condition of 2 consecutive matching numbers `XX` `YY` `ZZ` `KK`

Can someone tell me what can I add/remove to make it work?

Comment: Sounds very similar to your previous questions, still not able to use [capturing groups and backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) yourself? For this one try [`^5(?:(\d)\1){4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/tsr81O/1) (if it's just for validation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backreferences:

```
5(\d)\1(\d)\2(\d)\3(\d)\4
```

Sample script:

```py
inp = "533992288"
if re.search(r'^5(\d)\1(\d)\2(\d)\3(\d)\4$', inp):
    print("MATCH")
```

Comment: @anubhava ... or `^` and `$` anchors, depending on what the OP wants to do.